# Create 2 if-statements with their individual conditions and results

Tags: excel

I have a column of data which requires cleaning. An excerpt of the data can be found below:

```
    Column E
0    1109657
1    1109716
2    1109758
3    1109800
4    1109900
```

Column E is a cumulative sum, so one would expect it to keep increasing, as the rows go down. There are instances when the **next row misses a number e.g. row 1 is 110971 instead of 1109716** or **the next row adds on a number 11097581, instead of 1109758.** I have decided, if **the current row is 0.1 * (the previous row)**, I will multiply the current row by 10, or **if the current row is 1.1 * (the previous row)**, I will divide the current row by 10. How would implement this in excel, using two IF-statements? I am able to write both if-statements separately, but I would like to implement them in one go, on the column simultaneously

To multiply the current row by 10: `=IF(Current row<0.1*Previous row, Current row*10,Current row)`

To divide the current row by 10: `=IF(Current row>1.1*Previous row, Current row/10,Current row)`

Answer (score 1):

So just do the calculation for the other condition as the false argument:

=IF(Current row<0.1 * Previous row, Current row * 10,Current row/10)

This assumes that those are the only two condtions